# How to pass multiple props to conditional rendered styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have passed props to styled components before and am familiar with this convention.

```
<Card data={props.color}>

const Card = styled.div` 
 margin-right: ${(props) => (props.data === "BlueSquare" || "RedSquare" ? "5px" : "15px")};
`;
```

What I am having trouble with is converting this type of conditional styling to a styled component

```
background: linear-gradient(${ColorFunction({value: props.audited ? props.score : props.remScore,
})}, white);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Pass callback which accept props and return css property value in template literal with used values from props.

In your case, pass callback which accept props and return linear-gradient in template literal with used values from props.

```
background: ${props => `linear-gradient(${ColorFunction({value: props.audited ? props.score : props.remScore,
})}, white)`};
```